# MySQL In MEMORY tables to disk

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL MEMORY engine for creating table for minimizing the I/O.
As it stores the data in RAM i want another copy of data on disk for durability.

so my question is,
Is there a way to write the data of MEMORY table on disk ??

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, i keep in mind only two possible solution

```
INSERT INTO disk_table
SELECT * FROM ram_table
```

or

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = MEMORY;
ALTER TABLE t ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your table in InnoDB, and use

```
--innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit=0
```

for non-durable mode. You'll maintain your data on disk, but still have relatively high performance since commits are not synchronized immediately.

I'd at least test this scenario and see if its fast enough for you.